# Simultaneous Rotation,Scale in OpenGL with IdleFunc

Tags: opengl, 3d, cube

I want to rotate and increase/decrease the scale of my cube. The rotate part is ok :

```
void spinCube(){
double theta=0;
theta+= 0.1;
if( theta > 360.0 ) 
   theta -= 360.0;
glRotatef(theta,1,2,6);
glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

And I call this function in main in glutDisplayFunc():

```
glutIdleFunc(spinCube);
```

Also, while my cube is rotating I want to increase and decrease the scale factor of my cube.
I tried implementing this with the same way as rotation, for example:

```
void spinCube(){

double theta=0,x=0.1;
theta+= 0.1;
x+=0.1;
 if( theta > 360.0 ) 
    theta -= 360.0;
    if(x>4)
      x=0;
glScalef(x,x,x);
glRotatef(theta,1,2,6);
glutPostRedisplay();
```

}

**but the cube is no longer drawn**.
*Is there any solution to this problem*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Scaling of 0 is not valid. The correct value is 1 if you don't want to scale.

Comment: you are right.Well, can I ask you something else? I ahave my cube centered in the origin of coordinates.But let's say I want to move my cube to (0,0,-90) and then rotate the cube around itself, *not* around this center.How can I do this?

Comment: @johnjohn translate to origin, rotate, translate back. this should be easy if you keep track of the position using variables.

Comment: @AntonD and if I want also to scale(increase size and decrease size of the cube) simultaneously with rotation what do i do ?

Comment: Then you would say scale -> translate -> rotate